# Limiting the length of the announcement body using a custom webpart

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I am creating a custom webpart to display the content of an announcement list similar to that of the Summary View of List View webpart. However I am not able to limit the character length of announcement body to 250 characters due to the presence of rich content in the body. Due to the project requirement creating a custom webpart is essential and I cannot use the OOB list view webpart. Is there a way to achieve similar functionality through code?
Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Ankita

Answer (score 1):

You can use a method like below. This strips the HTML from your content, and displays plain text.

```
<xsl:template name="removeHtmlTags">
    <xsl:param name="html"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($html, '&lt;')">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($html, '&lt;')"/>
            <!-- Recurse through HTML -->
            <xsl:call-template name="removeHtmlTags">
                <xsl:with-param name="html" select="substring-after($html, '&gt;')"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$html"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Then you setup a variable which cleans the text:

```
<xsl:variable name="pureText">
    <xsl:call-template name="removeHtmlTags">
        <xsl:with-param name="html" select ="@Body" />
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:variable>
```

and finally, call this new variable and trim it down

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring($pureText, 0, 250)" />
```

HTH